# Rename domain using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, socialengine

I am working with Swiss website and this site has domain like "http://businessäftspartner.ch/" I have used SocialEngine4 with Zend framework to develop this site.

Now, the special character "ä" creating problem to upload images in the site as my system using fancyuploader to upload images and it require flash player on machine.

It is working fine for another domain name "http://xn--businessaftspartner-4kb.ch/".

So I want to rename domain from "businessäftspartner.ch" to "xn--businessaftspartner-4kb.ch". I tried many rules but it not worked.

Please let me know if any one have some idea.

Comment: please add your .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^businessäftspartner\.ch$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$       http://xn--businessaftspartner-4kb.ch$1   [R=301]
```